# Keyframe Creating Unwanted Actions

Tags: animation, keyframes, actions

https://youtu.be/GGXjHEIjB1w

Hi, I'm trying to create an animation of this armoire opening both doors at once, I have one bone for each door.
Here's a video of my problem but in short, whenever I create a keyframe, 5 actions get created with the bones or mesh being in a different random position in each action. The actions are different depending on which layer I select last when creating the initial keyframe. Any ideas on how to fix this?
Here is the file of the animation
[image]

[image: creating initial keyframe]

[image: First Unwanted Action Created]

[image: Second Unwanted Action Created]

[image: Third Unwanted Action Created]

[image: Fourth Unwanted Action Created]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, if you select several objects and press "i", it will create one action per object, and if you assign an action to object A then give it to object B, object B will inherit the location keyframe of the action that was originally given to object A. So maybe tell what you are trying to achieve and we will tell you how to do it?

Comment: Hi @moonboots, I updated the description, but I am trying to make an animation where both doors open at the same time. Normally when making this type of animation I just select everything, create an initial keyframe, and then rotate the two bones I have connected to the doors at 40 along the timeline and create a new keyframe there. However, now when I am creating the initial keyframe, the bones are going everywhere in the different actions, and I'm not sure why or how to stop this from happening.

Comment: I've explained the problem, you are keyframing each object, then you give the same action to all the objects, it can't work, also if you use bones why don't you simply parent the doors to the bones, switch to Pose mode and keyframe the bones?

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thanks for your response. I'm struggling a little to understand the extent of your answer. I understand that selecting each object will create a keyframe for each individual object and should shy away from doing that. However, what I am not understanding is that the only thing I am doing is creating the initial keyframe and not doing anything else. Yet, with each different action that is getting created off of that initial keyframe (because I selected all of the objects like you said) the bones are in a different position even though I didn't touch them. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you please share the file with the actions already created? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi @moonboots, I uploaded the file. Also, with this particular project, I shied away from using pose mode because I was unable to select both bones at once which means that I have to create two actions within the animation to open both doors at once. I'm not sure if this is normal or if there is something wrong with how I set up this mesh. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for example, you've created an action for *Cube.002* that is called *Cube.002Action*. An action is made of keyframes and keyframes are made of *Location/Rotation/Scale* data (or only *Location*, etc). If you select *DoorLeft* like you do in the video and give it the action called *Cube.002Action*, *DoorLeft* will inherit all the *Location/Rotation/Scale* data of the keyframe(s) of the action. For example *Cube.002Action* is made of a *Scale* keyframe on Z that is 2.06. If you give it to *DoorLeft*, this object will be scaled 2.06 times on Z. This is what happens here and that's all I see.

For something like your armoire, I'm not sure why you create all these actions. You just need to create one unique armature with 3 bones (one root bone and 2 bones for the doors), parent the mesh to the bones, switch the armature to *Pose* mode, keyframe.